# what line of code do I use to print out the input a user types in

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to coding, and I have been testing my skills with writing a small program to get better. I am trying to take the user input in, and print it back out to them. For example, if someone types their name into the system and the program responds with "there name" and continue saying whatever is next I programmed the program to say. So if anyone sees the problem I am running into and have any helpful input that would be great. Thanks to everyone for the help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Scanner
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Taking input using Scanner 
    System.out.println("Hello, How may I assist you today?");
    String name1 = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("where are you diving to today?");
    String name2 = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("what is your name?");   
    String name3 = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ok " + "new Scanner(System.in)");
    String name5 = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What time do you want to arrive to your destination?");
    String name6 = "new Scanner(System.in)";
    System.out.println(" + ", "new Scanner(System.in)" , " + " great, what time are you leaving? ");
    String name7 = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(" + " "new Scanner(System.in)" ," + ", "Good deal.");

}
```

}

Comment: `System.out.println("Hello " + name1);`?

Comment: Please click on the `Caps Lock` key.

Answer (score 1):

Use below statement for name1,

```
System.out.println("your string" + name1);
```

Similarly for other Strings.

So, your final code will look like

```
System.out.println("Hello, How may I assist you today?");
String name1 = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println("user input is: " + name1);
System.out.println("where are you driving to today?");
String name2 = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println("User input is: " + name2);
 System.out.println("I apolgize but I forgot to get your name?");   
String name3 = scanner.nextLine();
 System.out.println("Thanks" + name3);
```

Comment: when I try that method this is what happens,                    
Hello, How may I assist you today?
can you tell me the fastest way to get somewhere
where are you driving to today?
downtown austin
I apolgize but I forgot to get your name?
jennifer
Thanksname3

Comment: System.out.println("Hello, How may I assist you today?");
     String name1 = scanner.nextLine();
     System.out.println("where are you driving to today?");
     String name2 = scanner.nextLine();
     System.out.println("I apolgize but I forgot to get your name?");   
     String name3 = scanner.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Thanks" + "name3");

Comment: Please explain what do you want to ask?

Comment: I am trying to figure out the line of code to print out what the user is inputting to the system. For example if the user types there name. I want the the to respond. Ok "that persons name or etc" plus the message I want to print out with it.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Check if I answered your question. Wherever I have written like `System.out.println("user input is: " + name1);` , you can use `System.out.println(name1);` if you don't want to print `user input is` . And you have used name3 like "name3", so it will print name3 in console. Use `System.out.println("Thanks" + name3);`

Comment: Thanks, I will try that and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.